# Update XML file with XQuery Issue

Tags: xquery, exist-db, xquery-update

I am trying to update a node in an XML file using the following XQuery (in eXide):

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $update := doc('db/apps/xmlFiles/Customers.xml')//Customers[ID = 6]
return replace value of node $update/LastName with 'Morris'
```

but I receive this error that prevents me from running the query:

> error found while executing expression: org.exist.xquery.XPathException: err:XPST0003 unexpected token: value [at line 4, column 16]

Does anyone know what could be the problem with it? Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for a customer with that ID? If so, it would be `//Customers[ID=6]`. If a child, `//Customers/*[ID=6]`

Comment: As a note for the future -- any edit that removes so much information as to make previously-given answers inapplicable is considered bad form / not kosher here. When such an edit is appropriate (as opposed to asking a new, separate question -- which is more commonly the right thing), it should be done by adding additional information, but leaving the old information in place.

Comment: Anyhow -- now that you've made the correction I suggested, your new error is one I can't replicate in BaseX's implementation of XQUF (works perfectly there), so I'll need to defer to someone familiar with eXist.

Comment: ...although, one variance -- I use `db:open()` rather than `doc()` in my version.

Comment: sorry for my error in replacing the old code with the updated version, I'm new to this forum so am unaware with the rules and protocols of the site. I have tried db:open() in my code and the error message hasn't changed. Hmmm this is very weird and annoying!

Comment: @Lloyd Welcome to SO! First thing you should know is that this isn't a forum, but a Q&A (a very important distinction for us). Regarding your question I think eXist simply doesn't support the XQuery Update Facility, so you will have to use their implementation-specific Update statements (see http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/update_ext.xml). As said by Charles, a XQUF compliant processor like BaseX will work just fine with your query.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @dirkk, eXist does not support the XQUF 1.0, instead it implements an early draft version of XQUF. However, you can still do what you want to with this code:

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $update := doc('db/apps/xmlFiles/Customers.xml')//Customers[ID = 6]
return
    update value $update/LastName with 'Morris'
```

Note that in eXist updates are applies immediately in-place to the node in the database, as opposed to XQUF 1.0 where a PUL (Pending Update List) is created and then applied when the query finishes.